# flutter MultiSelectBottomSheetField the chip does not display when I am pushing current data

Tags: flutter, firebase, multi-select

I am trying to fix my code but so far I have not find any solution. I have done a lot of research and even used AI, but no solution works so far.
Let me give you more color.

I am using Firebase. I have a document with an array of map. They keys are id, name, phone, email.

when the view is displayed, I am getting the data.  I am also collecting in a list, all the contacts of my phone. I just need again the id, name, email and phone number.

What I am trying to achieve is that when the UI is displayed, I have chips with only the name of the contact selected (contacts coming from firebase). I am attaching a screenshot to make it more clear.[image]

On the screenshot, you can see the result I want to get. So that means that in Firebase, in an array, I have a map with id: 1234, name: Anna Haro, Phone: 06060606060, email: anna.haro@mail.com.
As this person is in my contacts on my phone IOS, I want to have a chip displayed confirming that I have delegated this task to this person.

```
List <MultiSelectItem<dynamic>> allContactsFromPhone = [];
List<MultiSelectItem<dynamic>> currentContacts = [];
```

```
 child: MultiSelectBottomSheetField(
                                      isDismissible: false,
                                      selectedColor: theme.primaryColor,
                                      backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor,
                                      key: _multiSelectKeyContact,
                                      initialChildSize: 0.7,
                                      maxChildSize: 0.95,
                                      buttonIcon: const Icon(
                                          Icons.arrow_downward_outlined),
                                      title: Text(
                                        'Delegated to:',
                                        style: theme.textTheme.bodyText1,
                                      ),
                                      buttonText: Text('Choose who you delegate to',
                                          style: theme.textTheme.headline6),
                                      searchTextStyle:
                                      theme.textTheme.headline6,
                                      searchHintStyle:
                                      theme.textTheme.headline6,
                                      itemsTextStyle: theme.textTheme.headline6,
                                      selectedItemsTextStyle:
                                      theme.textTheme.headline6,
                                      items: allContactsFromPhone,
                                      initialValue: currentContacts,
                                      searchable: true,
                                      onConfirm: (valueContact) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          _contactSelected = (valueContact);
                                        });
                                        _multiSelectKeyContact.currentState!.validate();
                                      },
                                      chipDisplay:  MultiSelectChipDisplay(
                                        chipColor: theme.primaryColorLight,
                                        textStyle: theme.textTheme.bodyText1,
                                        onTap: (dynamic item) {
                                          setState(() {});
                                          _multiSelectKeyContact.currentState!.validate();
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
```

```
 WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      final deviceContacts = await getContactsFromDevice();
      setState(() {
        allContactsFromPhone = deviceContacts!.map((e) => MultiSelectItem(e.id, e.displayName)).toList();

        for (var item in allContactsFromPhone) {
          print('Value: ${item.value}, Label: ${item.label}');
        }
      });
    });
```

```
currentContacts = widget.myDocument.delegated_To!
        .map((contact) => MultiSelectItem<dynamic>(contact.id, contact.name))
        .toList();

    for (var item in currentContacts) {
      print('my Value: ${item.value}, Label: ${item.label}');
    }
```

```
 Future<List<Contact>?> getContactsFromDevice() async {
    final contacts = await getContact();
    return contacts?.toList();
  }
```